# Google audio to text API but return null

Tags: google-cloud-speech

I have send below JSON request but I am getting below error.

JSON Request:-

```
{
  "config": {
    "enableAutomaticPunctuation": "true",
    "encoding": "MULAW",
    "languageCode": "en-US",
    "model": "default",
    "sampleRateHertz": 8000
  },
  "audio": {
    "content": "QzpcU3BlZWNoVG9UZXh0XGVuZ2xpc2hcUENNXDIud2F2"
  }
}
```

Output: null

Method for Encoding of wav file as given below

```
byte[] encodedAudio = Base64.encodeBase64(pcmFilePath.getBytes());
String s = new String(encodedAudio);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `pcmFilePath` is a `String`, then `pcmFilePath.getBytes()` will return the path to the file. Therefore, `encodedAudio` will contain the path to the file, not the encoded audio.

One way to get the contents of the file would be to use [`java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllBytes(java.nio.file.Path)) introduced in JDK 7.

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

byte[] pcmBytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(pcmFilePath));
byte[] encodedAudio = Base64.encodeBase64(pcmBytes);
```